# Loading a javascript library in javax.script?

Tags: java, javascript, javax.script, protovis

I want to run [**Protovis**](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) javascript from Java and get the evaluated SVG code.  I am using javax.script.* to run the Javascript:

```
public static void EvalScript() throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    Object result = engine.eval("var vis = new pv.Panel().width(300).height(300)
        .add (pv.Line).data ([1,0.5, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.3, 0.2,0.1,1])
           .left (function () { return this.index * 30; })
           .bottom (function (d) { return d * 250; });
        vis.root.render();
        vis.scene[0].canvas.innerHTML;");         
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

This would complain because I never loaded Protovis itself, as would ordinarily be done with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../protovis-r3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Is there a good way, short of sourcing in the full Javascript into the eval() command, of loading a library when running Javascript through javax.script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well why would you not load the whole script in and hand it to `eval()`?  If you want that Javascript execution context to parse and interpret the library, then *something* has to do that.  You could of course supply a mechanism to the script context to let the script itself do the equivalent of the `<script>` tag example you gave, but it would end up being exactly the same thing.

I don't understand your comment about Rhino. The Javascript interpreter in JDK 1.6 *is* Rhino.

Comment: Thanks.  Not that I don't want to do this; just wondering if there is a better way rather than opening a FileReader and passing it to eval.  I removed the Rhino comment.  I just wanted to include that link for reference, although I know that it is Rhino.

Comment: OK, well cool then. The way I've done this in the past is to really provide both tricks: as a general service to the app, I'd "stuff" a couple of standard libraries into each Javascript environment.  Then, I'd hook up a couple of APIs so that from the Javascript side, utility libraries could be loaded. (I was working in a web app, so the loading was always done through "getResourceAsStream", but loading from files or a PATH would be essentially the same.) Providing a Javascript-domain hook is nice if there are lots of libraries or little utility packages.